# Cannot create s3 bucket in sydney using PHP SDK2

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm getting the following error when I try to create s3 bucket in Sydney Region using PHP SDK 2:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Service\Exception\ValidationException' with message 'Validation errors:
[LocationConstraint] must be one of "EU" or "eu-west-1" or "us-west-1" or "us-west-2" or "ap-southeast-1" or "ap-northeast-1" or "sa-east-1"'
```

The error has no ap-southeast-2 in the list of regions. I have tried two different versions of SDK (2.2.x and 2.4.3). Still the same error. Anybody had the same issue and know any work around?

Comment: Could you show the code you are using to create the bucket?

Comment: @Christian                                                `$param=array('Bucket'=>'bucket-sydney', 'LocationConstraint'=>'ap-southeast-2');
$ret = $s3client->createBucket($param);`

  I have tried these too

`$param=array('Bucket'=>'bucket-sydney', 'LocationConstraint'=>Region::AP_SOUTH_EAST_2);
$param=array('Bucket'=>'bucket-sydney', 'LocationConstraint'=>Region::SYDNEY)`

Answer (score 2):

That's a bug. I just [committed a fix](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/commit/d332784fc69594e47fa9ba84e07033e1a10f80ea) for you.

Comment: Hey, a familiar face :)

Comment: @Jeremy How do I get your fix? I am using aws.phar and I do not have the file called src/Aws/S3/Resources/s3-2006-03-01.php

Comment: The aws.phar gets updated when we do releases. We just did one today (2.4.6), so you should be able to redownload the phar to get the fix.